# ChromeDriver screenshot not showing whole document if window size were set?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Using chrome selenium driver, I am not getting screenshots showing the whole document if the browser dimension was set by me instead of just keeping the dimensions I got automatically.

I create my chrome driver like this:

```
IWebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();

browser.Manage().Window.Size = new Size(1024, 768);
```

I take the screenshot like this:

```
var screenshot = browser.TakeScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile("c:\\screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

The screenshot size will be 1014x686, which is expected, because it should only cover the document, but to depicts the bottom part of the webpage instead of the whole webpage.

Why?

If I am not setting the window size, the screenshot seems to be correct.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium: chrome driver makes screenshot just of visible part of page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885169/selenium-chrome-driver-makes-screenshot-just-of-visible-part-of-page)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a limitation of the current Chrome driver. It's been logged as [an issue in their issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=294). The driver bug, in turn, is dependent on a fix for [a bug in Chromium itself](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=45209). Until the parent bug in Chromium is fixed, there's nothing that chromedriver or the Selenium project can do to work around the problem with a proper amount of reliability and fidelity.